# I got syntax error in pharo when dragging in a file

Tags: syntax-error, drag, smalltalk, pharo

I started working with Pharo 1.4 and I wanted to load a file.st in order to work with extra classes and methods. What I did is dragging this file to pharo, and select "FileIn entire file". After doing this, a window pops up, stating: Syntax error: Nothing more expected. A loading message do not disappear. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably something with syntax :) Can you share a contents of you file? If it's large please use http://pastebin.com

Comment: why you use pharo 1.4 and not 2 or pharo 3  ? Can you reproduce the error or was it an one time error ? if yes please paste a full stack trace of your error.

Comment: More importantly: where did you have the .st file from? If it's from a Squeak image for example there are a couple of things in the syntax that might trigger a syntax error, such as the old assignment operator (underscore).

Answer (score 1):

Enric use Pharo2.0 (because 1.4 is now old). We are improving Pharo a lot. . I loaded it in 20 without any problem. I loaded it also in a fresh 1.4 and it loaded perfectly (doing install in new changeset and fileIn entire...).  Note in addition that we rarely import code this way. Finally if you send a mail to the mailing-list with your file you will get a real answer. 
If you want to close the annoying window you can use option/ctlr + shift click to bring the halos on any graphical element and destroy it.

Comment: But it is mandatory using 1.4 in this subject in the university. You say that loading in a fresh 1.4 it worked, how can I do this?

Comment: A _fresh image_ is one that you downloaded and haven't done any changes to. Especially when you experiment a lot it happens that you break some fundamental things. So it is a good idea to start with a fresh image from time to time (or very often).

Answer (score 0):

I chose pharo 1.4 because the teacher says i need to work with this one. The file is from:
http://db.tt/cHUi7oz6
and I saved it in the Desktop as a .st file (i removed the .txt format). Once saved, I dragged and drop the file in the pharo window and chose the option "FileIn entire file", and the error pop up. It says syntax error: Nothing more expected. Undefined object . And there is a message that does not disappear or does anything, saying "loading nameoffile.st".

Comment: I tried with Pharo 1.4 and 2.0 and in both cases it loaded without problem and i could run the examples. Are you sure you did not change the file in any way? Have you tried with a fresh image?

Comment: I didn't change anything, surely. What do you mean fresh image?

Comment: By _fresh image_ i meant one that you downloaded and haven't done any changes to. Especially when you experiment a lot it happens that you break some fundamental things. So it is a good idea to start with a fresh image from time to time (or very often).